# Как растянуть background-image на всю ширину и высоту в фиксированном блоке?

Tags: html, css

Ширина и высота самого блока может меняться!

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%0A%3Csvg id='Firefox_-_Large' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 0 1024 1024'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient' cx='-14480.522' cy='-8329.079' fx='-14509.281265145226' r='450.875' gradientTransform='matrix(0.762, 0.034, -0.05, 1.12, 11560.893, 10069.103)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.045' stop-color='%23ffea00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.12' stop-color='%23ffde00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.254' stop-color='%23ffbf00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.429' stop-color='%23ff8e00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.769' stop-color='%23ff272d'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.872' stop-color='%23e0255a'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.953' stop-color='%23cc2477'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23c42482'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-2' cx='-7529.669' cy='-7921.608' r='791.229' gradientTransform='translate(9921.963 9899.103) scale(1.225 1.225)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%2300ccda'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.22' stop-color='%230083ff'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.261' stop-color='%23007af9'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.33' stop-color='%230060e8'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.333' stop-color='%23005fe7'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.438' stop-color='%232639ad'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.522' stop-color='%23401e84'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.566' stop-color='%234a1475'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient' x1='575.669' y1='731.188' x2='384.231' y2='104.96' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23000f43' stop-opacity='0.4'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.485' stop-color='%23001962' stop-opacity='0.173'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23002079' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-3' cx='-8260.94' cy='-6516.556' r='266.886' gradientTransform='matrix(1.219, 0.123, -0.123, 1.219, 10296.265, 9597.23)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.003' stop-color='%23ffea00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.497' stop-color='%23ff272d'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23c42482'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-4' cx='-8285.087' cy='-6772.468' r='445.678' gradientTransform='matrix(1.219, 0.123, -0.123, 1.219, 10296.265, 9597.23)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.003' stop-color='%23ffe900'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.157' stop-color='%23ffaf0e'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.316' stop-color='%23ff7a1b'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.472' stop-color='%23ff4e26'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.621' stop-color='%23ff2c2e'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.762' stop-color='%23ff1434'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.892' stop-color='%23ff0538'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23ff0039'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-5' cx='-8222.051' cy='-6359.332' r='408.958' gradientTransform='matrix(1.219, 0.123, -0.123, 1.219, 10296.265, 9597.23)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.003' stop-color='%23ff272d'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.497' stop-color='%23c42482'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.986' stop-color='%23620700'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-6' cx='750.189' cy='396.041' fx='778.1665281038617' fy='382.2124050106231' r='782.18' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.156' stop-color='%23ffea00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.231' stop-color='%23ffde00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.365' stop-color='%23ffbf00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.541' stop-color='%23ff8e00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.763' stop-color='%23ff272d'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.796' stop-color='%23f92433'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.841' stop-color='%23e91c45'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.893' stop-color='%23cf0e62'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.935' stop-color='%23b5007f'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-7' cx='691.339' cy='3.289' r='923.615' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.279' stop-color='%23ffea00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.402' stop-color='%23fd0'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.63' stop-color='%23ffba00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.856' stop-color='%23ff9100'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.933' stop-color='%23ff6711'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.994' stop-color='%23ff4a1d'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-2' x1='-8944.65' y1='-6677.742' x2='-8660.289' y2='-6750.226' gradientTransform='matrix(1.219, 0.123, -0.123, 1.219, 10296.265, 9597.23)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.474' stop-color='%23ff272d' stop-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.486' stop-color='%23ff2c2c' stop-opacity='0.513'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.675' stop-color='%23ff7a1a' stop-opacity='0.72'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.829' stop-color='%23ffb20d' stop-opacity='0.871'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.942' stop-color='%23ffd605' stop-opacity='0.964'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23ffe302'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-3' x1='245.347' y1='-1082.012' x2='190.775' y2='-1221.859' gradientTransform='matrix(0.995, 0.1, -0.1, 0.995, -173.696, 1313.941)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23891551' stop-opacity='0.6'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-4' x1='22.04' y1='718.827' x2='116.148' y2='825.714' gradientTransform='matrix(0.995, 0.1, -0.1, 0.995, 305.439, -246.471)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.005' stop-color='%23891551' stop-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.484' stop-color='%23ff272d' stop-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23ff272d' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-5' x1='200.104' y1='904.616' x2='200.171' y2='829.835' gradientTransform='matrix(0.995, 0.1, -0.1, 0.995, 305.439, -246.471)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23c42482'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.083' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.81'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.206' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.565'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.328' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.362'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.447' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.204'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.562' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.091'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.673' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.023'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.773' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-6' x1='655.531' y1='38.12' x2='961.187' y2='721.615' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23fff14f'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.268' stop-color='%23ffee4c'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.452' stop-color='%23ffe643'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.612' stop-color='%23ffd834'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.757' stop-color='%23ffc41e'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.892' stop-color='%23ffab02'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.902' stop-color='%23ffa900'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.949' stop-color='%23ffa000'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23ff9100'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-7' x1='715.885' y1='431.21' x2='571.098' y2='819.96' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23ff8e00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.04' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.858'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.084' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.729'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.13' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.628'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.178' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.557'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.227' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.514'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.282' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.389' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.478'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.524' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.416'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.676' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.314'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.838' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.172'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Ctitle%3Efirefox-logo%3C/title%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath d='M805.285,93.558c-23.947,27.884-35.1,90.639-10.818,154.256s61.5,49.8,84.7,114.673c30.623,85.6,16.369,200.589,16.369,200.589s36.814,106.609,62.468-6.633C1014.787,343.74,805.285,145.937,805.285,93.558Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient)'/%3E%3Cpath id='_Path_' d='M513.072,976.638c245.236,0,443.9-199.739,443.9-446.028S758.308,84.583,513.31,84.583,69.65,284.322,69.65,530.61C69.175,777.137,268.073,976.638,513.072,976.638Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-2)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M845.675,805.636a246.888,246.888,0,0,1-30.123,18.183,704,704,0,0,0,38.3-62.961c9.46-10.47,18.126-20.648,25.188-31.653,3.437-5.407,7.313-12.079,11.416-19.819,24.921-44.9,52.4-117.563,53.179-192.2l0-.18c.018-1.837.029-3.675.014-5.515a257.6,257.6,0,0,0-5.712-55.748c.2,1.431.376,2.861.556,4.291-.221-1.1-.407-2.212-.644-3.314.366,2.034.66,4,.976,5.983,5.094,43.217,1.466,85.372-16.682,116.45-.286.454-.58.879-.869,1.323,9.41-47.234,12.558-99.387,2.088-151.6,0,0-4.187-25.383-35.376-102.441-17.952-44.353-49.833-80.716-78-107.207-24.69-30.546-47.114-51.045-59.475-64.06-25.821-27.189-36.643-47.569-41.087-60.867-3.853-1.932-53.135-49.807-57.05-51.631-21.511,33.352-89.162,137.675-56.981,235.146,14.584,44.172,51.467,90.017,90.067,115.736,1.695,1.936,22.969,25.042,33.086,77.157C728.992,524.551,723.5,566.564,702,628.692c-25.286,54.505-90.067,108.388-150.724,113.9C421.6,754.373,374.127,677.484,374.127,677.484c46.336,18.525,97.568,14.65,128.724-4.556,31.4-19.425,50.394-33.827,65.81-28.148,15.2,5.653,27.3-10.756,16.442-27.767a78.5,78.5,0,0,0-79.4-34.573c-31.433,5.109-60.226,30.009-101.412,5.894a85.528,85.528,0,0,1-7.729-5.062c-2.715-1.785,8.826,2.717,6.133.688-8.015-4.354-22.2-13.842-25.88-17.217-.613-.562,6.219,2.179,5.606,1.616-38.51-31.712-33.7-53.134-32.49-66.57.969-10.749,7.964-24.523,19.751-30.11,5.693,3.107,9.24,5.479,9.24,5.479s-2.428-4.961-3.741-7.576c.46-.2.9-.147,1.358-.342,4.664,2.251,14.977,8.1,20.407,11.667,7.072,4.988,9.326,9.436,9.326,9.436s1.862-1.025.485-5.375c-.5-1.784-2.647-7.453-9.652-13.174l.438.049a81.2,81.2,0,0,1,11.867,8.241c1.975-7.181,5.527-14.679,4.746-28.092-.477-9.431-.257-11.873-1.919-15.515-1.488-3.128.834-4.348,3.418-1.1a32.826,32.826,0,0,0-2.208-7.4l.022-.244c3.225-11.236,68.248-40.461,72.981-43.877a67.355,67.355,0,0,0,19.132-20.8c3.617-5.763,6.337-13.848,7-26.112.355-8.844-3.759-14.734-69.507-21.618-17.981-1.771-28.531-14.8-34.526-26.823-1.094-2.59-2.209-4.937-3.325-7.282a58,58,0,0,1-2.558-8.431c10.749-30.873,28.81-56.977,55.367-76.7,1.447-1.318-5.782.338-4.336-.98,1.687-1.538,12.706-5.977,14.787-6.977,2.542-1.2-10.882-6.9-22.732-5.512-12.069,1.36-14.632,2.8-21.073,5.531,2.673-2.661,11.173-6.149,9.18-6.126-13.011,1.995-29.179,9.558-43,18.124a10.731,10.731,0,0,1,.835-4.348c-6.441,2.732-22.26,13.788-26.865,23.142a44.329,44.329,0,0,0,.266-5.4A84.483,84.483,0,0,0,351.9,227.362l-.241.219c-37.358-15.05-70.233-16.024-98.053-9.276-6.086-6.112-9.059-1.644-22.907-32.069-.941-1.832.722,1.809,0,0-2.278-5.9,1.389,7.872,0,0-23.284,18.372-53.92,39.193-68.626,53.89-.182.586,17.156-4.9,0,0-6.008,1.716-5.6,5.281-6.513,37.5-.22,2.443-.025,5.179-.223,7.378-11.748,14.968-19.749,27.643-22.775,34.211-15.193,26.18-31.926,66.992-48.146,131.551A334.364,334.364,0,0,1,110.2,400.365c-13.488,34.267-26.527,88.078-29.134,170.945a483.614,483.614,0,0,1,12.533-50.66,473.038,473.038,0,0,0,34.74,201.061c9.329,22.821,24.76,57.455,51.029,95.4,82.533,86.839,198.945,140.9,327.852,140.9C641.792,958.012,762.635,899.133,845.675,805.636Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M746.1,868.708c162.87-18.86,234.969-186.7,142.381-190-83.633-2.673-219.527,198.9-142.381,190Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-3)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M900.207,644.424c112.056-65.214,82.839-206.08,82.839-206.08S939.8,488.582,910.421,568.664C881.4,647.963,832.837,683.812,900.207,644.424Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-4)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M544.474,952.062c156.227,49.851,290.5-73.22,207.733-114.32C676.956,800.676,470.324,928.49,544.474,952.062Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-5)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M911.849,704.234c3.8-5.363,8.94-22.535,13.48-30.211C952.911,629.5,953.106,594,953.106,593.187c16.659-83.219,15.148-117.2,4.9-180.043-8.251-50.6-44.322-123.092-75.57-158-32.2-35.965-9.514-24.247-40.692-50.518-27.327-30.293-53.823-60.291-68.253-72.355C669.215,45.094,671.571,26.577,673.579,23.42c-.339.371-.837.922-1.472,1.643C670.872,20.14,670,16,670,16s-57,57-69,152c-7.834,62.021,15.383,126.676,49,168a381.367,381.367,0,0,0,59,58l0-.026c25.4,36.477,39.38,81.489,39.38,129.909,0,121.244-98.341,219.531-219.652,219.531a220.455,220.455,0,0,1-49.134-5.519c-57.236-10.908-90.288-39.781-106.772-59.382-9.447-11.234-13.464-19.423-13.464-19.423,51.283,18.371,107.986,14.528,142.468-4.518,34.749-19.265,55.774-33.546,72.837-27.915,16.82,5.606,30.211-10.667,18.2-27.536-11.771-16.845-42.4-40.97-87.878-34.286-34.789,5.067-66.657,29.76-112.24,5.845a96.313,96.313,0,0,1-8.554-5.02c-3.005-1.771,9.768,2.695,6.787.682-8.87-4.318-24.573-13.728-28.643-17.074-.679-.557,6.883,2.161,6.2,1.6-42.621-31.449-37.3-52.693-35.959-66.018,1.073-10.66,8.814-24.32,21.859-29.86,6.3,3.081,10.226,5.433,10.226,5.433s-2.688-4.92-4.141-7.513c.509-.194.994-.145,1.5-.339,5.162,2.232,16.576,8.029,22.586,11.57,7.827,4.947,10.322,9.358,10.322,9.358s2.061-1.016.536-5.33c-.557-1.769-2.929-7.391-10.682-13.065l.485.049a90.851,90.851,0,0,1,13.134,8.173c2.186-7.121,6.118-14.557,5.253-27.859-.528-9.352-.284-11.775-2.124-15.386-1.647-3.1.924-4.312,3.782-1.088a30.038,30.038,0,0,0-2.444-7.343l.025-.242c3.57-11.143,75.535-40.125,80.773-43.513a70.31,70.31,0,0,0,21.175-20.63c4-5.715,7.014-13.733,7.748-25.895.246-5.48-1.441-9.817-20.5-13.965-11.439-2.49-29.136-4.913-56.433-7.474-19.9-1.756-31.577-14.676-38.212-26.6-1.211-2.569-2.445-4.9-3.68-7.222a53.108,53.108,0,0,1-2.831-8.36,158.47,158.47,0,0,1,61.279-76.063c1.6-1.308-6.4.335-4.8-.972,1.868-1.525,14.063-5.927,16.367-6.919,2.813-1.186-12.044-6.84-25.159-5.466-13.357,1.349-16.194,2.776-23.323,5.486,2.959-2.639,12.366-6.1,10.161-6.075-14.4,1.978-32.3,9.479-47.6,17.973a9.676,9.676,0,0,1,.924-4.312c-7.129,2.709-24.637,13.674-29.734,22.95a39.488,39.488,0,0,0,.294-5.354,88.678,88.678,0,0,0-14.6,13.7l-.267.218c-41.347-14.925-77.732-15.891-108.522-9.2-6.736-6.061-17.566-15.226-32.892-45.4-1.041-1.817-1.6,3.755-2.4,1.961-5.955-13.813-9.553-36.444-8.962-52.046,0,0-12.318,5.614-22.513,29.06-1.893,4.215-3.107,6.54-4.32,8.865-.558.678,1.265-7.7.974-7.244-1.772,3-6.356,7.192-8.371,12.618-1.384,4.021-3.325,6.273-4.564,11.288l-.291.46c-.1-1.478.367-6.081.027-5.137a236.1,236.1,0,0,0-12.308,29.841c-5.489,18.046-11.879,42.61-12.892,74.565-.244,2.423-.027,5.136-.247,7.317-13,14.844-21.858,27.413-25.207,33.928C75.18,329.762,56.66,370.236,38.707,434.259A319.143,319.143,0,0,1,67.245,384.27C52.316,418.253,37.885,471.618,35,553.8a438.522,438.522,0,0,1,13.872-50.24c-2.578,54.8,3.805,122.74,38.449,199.393,20.57,45.087,67.921,136.649,183.62,208.1l-.01.007s39.36,29.3,107.017,51.259c5,1.814,10.065,3.6,15.234,5.333-1.622-.655-3.191-1.344-4.715-2.052a484.883,484.883,0,0,0,138.8,20.4c175.18.149,226.846-70.2,226.846-70.2s-.182.137-.513.377q3.708-3.491,7.143-7.257c-27.639,26.1-90.715,27.832-114.3,25.949,40.223-11.813,66.691-21.806,118.175-41.519Q773.655,890,783.1,885.71c.681-.3,1.368-.625,2.052-.936,1.249-.582,2.486-1.132,3.747-1.744a349.205,349.205,0,0,0,70.262-43.987c51.7-41.3,62.949-81.557,68.829-108.1-.82,2.544-3.375,8.475-5.17,12.316-13.315,28.482-42.841,45.959-74.908,60.948A688.993,688.993,0,0,0,890.3,741.773C900.767,731.39,904.033,715.148,911.849,704.234Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-6)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M848.921,802.982c21.08-23.241,40.01-49.824,54.349-79.968,36.9-77.582,93.952-206.58,49.018-341.306C916.775,275.225,868.016,217,806.107,160.122,705.563,67.756,677.482,26.521,677.482,2c0,0-116.089,129.409-65.742,264.381S765.2,396.405,833.419,537.255C913.694,703,768.47,883.869,648.375,934.493c7.353-1.633,266.97-60.383,280.614-208.882C928.68,728.342,922.83,769.414,848.921,802.982Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-7)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M512.592,321.373c.393-8.77-4.156-14.66-76.682-21.463-29.839-2.755-41.265-30.334-44.748-41.941-10.61,27.565-14.991,56.49-12.636,91.477,1.61,22.92,17.009,47.521,24.37,61.965,0,0,1.636-2.126,2.391-2.912,13.861-14.431,71.936-36.419,77.392-39.541C488.693,365.159,511.582,348.435,512.592,321.373Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-2)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M193.314,158.471c-1.041-1.818-1.6,3.754-2.4,1.961-5.955-13.813-9.578-36.2-8.72-52.022,0,0-12.318,5.614-22.513,29.06-1.893,4.215-3.107,6.54-4.32,8.865-.558.678,1.265-7.7.974-7.244-1.771,3-6.355,7.192-8.346,12.375-1.651,4.239-3.349,6.515-4.613,11.772-.389,1.429.392-6.323.052-5.379-23.711,45.825-28.237,115.114-25.738,112.184,50.478-53.9,108.325-66.683,108.325-66.683-6.155-4.534-19.528-17.625-32.7-44.889Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-3)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M384.844,722.1c-69.724-29.769-148.992-71.755-146-167.138,4.075-125.619,117.145-100.791,117.145-100.791-4.267,1.039-15.675,9.162-19.718,17.82-4.273,10.827-12.069,35.276,11.551,60.9,37.089,40.192-76.2,95.356,98.663,199.567,4.41,2.4-40.991-1.43-61.639-10.358Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-4)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M360.074,659.5c49.442,17.207,107.04,14.189,141.523-4.858,23.085-12.851,52.7-33.434,70.922-28.353-15.777-6.236-27.726-9.15-42.1-9.862-2.448,0-5.382-.052-8.048-.32a136.228,136.228,0,0,0-15.757.863c-8.9.818-18.766,6.433-27.735,5.532-.485-.049,8.7-3.774,7.953-3.605-4.752.991-9.915,1.205-15.37,1.881-3.467.386-6.449.82-9.891.963-102.982,8.733-190.017-55.813-190.017-55.813-7.408,24.95,33.166,74.3,88.521,93.572Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-5)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M848.738,803.646C952.9,701.376,1005.6,577.061,983.321,437.627c0,0,8.9,71.5-24.848,144.628,16.213-71.393,18.1-160.114-24.975-251.988C876.005,207.636,781.45,143.109,745.351,116.189,690.656,75.4,667.983,33.87,667.574,25.3c-16.339,33.477-65.766,148.2-5.31,247,56.64,92.564,145.865,120.039,208.328,204.947C985.667,633.667,848.738,803.646,848.738,803.646Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-6)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M833.814,537.551C797.412,462.35,751.978,429.55,709,394c5,7,6.232,9.473,9,14,37.827,40.316,93.607,138.656,53.11,262.107C694.881,902.482,389.967,793.057,358,762.319c12.932,134.489,238.036,198.845,384.6,111.63C826,795,893.468,660.788,833.814,537.551Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-7)'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 360px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: `background-size: cover;`

Comment: @InDevX, `cover` не сработает, он заполняет по одной минимальной стороне, получится обрезанная

Comment: Удалил бесполезный ответ свой. Но, прогресс на лицо. Что сейчас не так, как блок должен выглядеть?

Comment: Вариант через `<img>` не подходит?

Comment: @InDevX, добавил ответ, нашел решение, вроде срабатывает, не знай только как с совместимостью

Answer (score 0):

Что бы растянуть и ширину и высоту используйте 2 значения:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

```css
body {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%0A%3Csvg preserveAspectRatio='none' id='Firefox_-_Large' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 0 1024 1024'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient' cx='-14480.522' cy='-8329.079' fx='-14509.281265145226' r='450.875' gradientTransform='matrix(0.762, 0.034, -0.05, 1.12, 11560.893, 10069.103)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.045' stop-color='%23ffea00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.12' stop-color='%23ffde00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.254' stop-color='%23ffbf00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.429' stop-color='%23ff8e00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.769' stop-color='%23ff272d'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.872' stop-color='%23e0255a'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.953' stop-color='%23cc2477'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23c42482'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-2' cx='-7529.669' cy='-7921.608' r='791.229' gradientTransform='translate(9921.963 9899.103) scale(1.225 1.225)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%2300ccda'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.22' stop-color='%230083ff'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.261' stop-color='%23007af9'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.33' stop-color='%230060e8'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.333' stop-color='%23005fe7'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.438' stop-color='%232639ad'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.522' stop-color='%23401e84'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.566' stop-color='%234a1475'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient' x1='575.669' y1='731.188' x2='384.231' y2='104.96' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23000f43' stop-opacity='0.4'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.485' stop-color='%23001962' stop-opacity='0.173'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23002079' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-3' cx='-8260.94' cy='-6516.556' r='266.886' gradientTransform='matrix(1.219, 0.123, -0.123, 1.219, 10296.265, 9597.23)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.003' stop-color='%23ffea00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.497' stop-color='%23ff272d'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23c42482'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-4' cx='-8285.087' cy='-6772.468' r='445.678' gradientTransform='matrix(1.219, 0.123, -0.123, 1.219, 10296.265, 9597.23)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.003' stop-color='%23ffe900'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.157' stop-color='%23ffaf0e'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.316' stop-color='%23ff7a1b'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.472' stop-color='%23ff4e26'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.621' stop-color='%23ff2c2e'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.762' stop-color='%23ff1434'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.892' stop-color='%23ff0538'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23ff0039'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-5' cx='-8222.051' cy='-6359.332' r='408.958' gradientTransform='matrix(1.219, 0.123, -0.123, 1.219, 10296.265, 9597.23)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.003' stop-color='%23ff272d'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.497' stop-color='%23c42482'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.986' stop-color='%23620700'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-6' cx='750.189' cy='396.041' fx='778.1665281038617' fy='382.2124050106231' r='782.18' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.156' stop-color='%23ffea00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.231' stop-color='%23ffde00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.365' stop-color='%23ffbf00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.541' stop-color='%23ff8e00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.763' stop-color='%23ff272d'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.796' stop-color='%23f92433'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.841' stop-color='%23e91c45'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.893' stop-color='%23cf0e62'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.935' stop-color='%23b5007f'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-7' cx='691.339' cy='3.289' r='923.615' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.279' stop-color='%23ffea00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.402' stop-color='%23fd0'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.63' stop-color='%23ffba00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.856' stop-color='%23ff9100'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.933' stop-color='%23ff6711'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.994' stop-color='%23ff4a1d'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-2' x1='-8944.65' y1='-6677.742' x2='-8660.289' y2='-6750.226' gradientTransform='matrix(1.219, 0.123, -0.123, 1.219, 10296.265, 9597.23)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.474' stop-color='%23ff272d' stop-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.486' stop-color='%23ff2c2c' stop-opacity='0.513'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.675' stop-color='%23ff7a1a' stop-opacity='0.72'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.829' stop-color='%23ffb20d' stop-opacity='0.871'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.942' stop-color='%23ffd605' stop-opacity='0.964'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23ffe302'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-3' x1='245.347' y1='-1082.012' x2='190.775' y2='-1221.859' gradientTransform='matrix(0.995, 0.1, -0.1, 0.995, -173.696, 1313.941)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23891551' stop-opacity='0.6'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-4' x1='22.04' y1='718.827' x2='116.148' y2='825.714' gradientTransform='matrix(0.995, 0.1, -0.1, 0.995, 305.439, -246.471)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.005' stop-color='%23891551' stop-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.484' stop-color='%23ff272d' stop-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23ff272d' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-5' x1='200.104' y1='904.616' x2='200.171' y2='829.835' gradientTransform='matrix(0.995, 0.1, -0.1, 0.995, 305.439, -246.471)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23c42482'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.083' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.81'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.206' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.565'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.328' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.362'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.447' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.204'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.562' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.091'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.673' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.023'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.773' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-6' x1='655.531' y1='38.12' x2='961.187' y2='721.615' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23fff14f'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.268' stop-color='%23ffee4c'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.452' stop-color='%23ffe643'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.612' stop-color='%23ffd834'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.757' stop-color='%23ffc41e'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.892' stop-color='%23ffab02'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.902' stop-color='%23ffa900'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.949' stop-color='%23ffa000'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23ff9100'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-7' x1='715.885' y1='431.21' x2='571.098' y2='819.96' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23ff8e00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.04' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.858'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.084' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.729'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.13' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.628'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.178' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.557'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.227' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.514'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.282' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.389' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.478'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.524' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.416'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.676' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.314'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.838' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.172'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Ctitle%3Efirefox-logo%3C/title%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath d='M805.285,93.558c-23.947,27.884-35.1,90.639-10.818,154.256s61.5,49.8,84.7,114.673c30.623,85.6,16.369,200.589,16.369,200.589s36.814,106.609,62.468-6.633C1014.787,343.74,805.285,145.937,805.285,93.558Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient)'/%3E%3Cpath id='_Path_' d='M513.072,976.638c245.236,0,443.9-199.739,443.9-446.028S758.308,84.583,513.31,84.583,69.65,284.322,69.65,530.61C69.175,777.137,268.073,976.638,513.072,976.638Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-2)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M845.675,805.636a246.888,246.888,0,0,1-30.123,18.183,704,704,0,0,0,38.3-62.961c9.46-10.47,18.126-20.648,25.188-31.653,3.437-5.407,7.313-12.079,11.416-19.819,24.921-44.9,52.4-117.563,53.179-192.2l0-.18c.018-1.837.029-3.675.014-5.515a257.6,257.6,0,0,0-5.712-55.748c.2,1.431.376,2.861.556,4.291-.221-1.1-.407-2.212-.644-3.314.366,2.034.66,4,.976,5.983,5.094,43.217,1.466,85.372-16.682,116.45-.286.454-.58.879-.869,1.323,9.41-47.234,12.558-99.387,2.088-151.6,0,0-4.187-25.383-35.376-102.441-17.952-44.353-49.833-80.716-78-107.207-24.69-30.546-47.114-51.045-59.475-64.06-25.821-27.189-36.643-47.569-41.087-60.867-3.853-1.932-53.135-49.807-57.05-51.631-21.511,33.352-89.162,137.675-56.981,235.146,14.584,44.172,51.467,90.017,90.067,115.736,1.695,1.936,22.969,25.042,33.086,77.157C728.992,524.551,723.5,566.564,702,628.692c-25.286,54.505-90.067,108.388-150.724,113.9C421.6,754.373,374.127,677.484,374.127,677.484c46.336,18.525,97.568,14.65,128.724-4.556,31.4-19.425,50.394-33.827,65.81-28.148,15.2,5.653,27.3-10.756,16.442-27.767a78.5,78.5,0,0,0-79.4-34.573c-31.433,5.109-60.226,30.009-101.412,5.894a85.528,85.528,0,0,1-7.729-5.062c-2.715-1.785,8.826,2.717,6.133.688-8.015-4.354-22.2-13.842-25.88-17.217-.613-.562,6.219,2.179,5.606,1.616-38.51-31.712-33.7-53.134-32.49-66.57.969-10.749,7.964-24.523,19.751-30.11,5.693,3.107,9.24,5.479,9.24,5.479s-2.428-4.961-3.741-7.576c.46-.2.9-.147,1.358-.342,4.664,2.251,14.977,8.1,20.407,11.667,7.072,4.988,9.326,9.436,9.326,9.436s1.862-1.025.485-5.375c-.5-1.784-2.647-7.453-9.652-13.174l.438.049a81.2,81.2,0,0,1,11.867,8.241c1.975-7.181,5.527-14.679,4.746-28.092-.477-9.431-.257-11.873-1.919-15.515-1.488-3.128.834-4.348,3.418-1.1a32.826,32.826,0,0,0-2.208-7.4l.022-.244c3.225-11.236,68.248-40.461,72.981-43.877a67.355,67.355,0,0,0,19.132-20.8c3.617-5.763,6.337-13.848,7-26.112.355-8.844-3.759-14.734-69.507-21.618-17.981-1.771-28.531-14.8-34.526-26.823-1.094-2.59-2.209-4.937-3.325-7.282a58,58,0,0,1-2.558-8.431c10.749-30.873,28.81-56.977,55.367-76.7,1.447-1.318-5.782.338-4.336-.98,1.687-1.538,12.706-5.977,14.787-6.977,2.542-1.2-10.882-6.9-22.732-5.512-12.069,1.36-14.632,2.8-21.073,5.531,2.673-2.661,11.173-6.149,9.18-6.126-13.011,1.995-29.179,9.558-43,18.124a10.731,10.731,0,0,1,.835-4.348c-6.441,2.732-22.26,13.788-26.865,23.142a44.329,44.329,0,0,0,.266-5.4A84.483,84.483,0,0,0,351.9,227.362l-.241.219c-37.358-15.05-70.233-16.024-98.053-9.276-6.086-6.112-9.059-1.644-22.907-32.069-.941-1.832.722,1.809,0,0-2.278-5.9,1.389,7.872,0,0-23.284,18.372-53.92,39.193-68.626,53.89-.182.586,17.156-4.9,0,0-6.008,1.716-5.6,5.281-6.513,37.5-.22,2.443-.025,5.179-.223,7.378-11.748,14.968-19.749,27.643-22.775,34.211-15.193,26.18-31.926,66.992-48.146,131.551A334.364,334.364,0,0,1,110.2,400.365c-13.488,34.267-26.527,88.078-29.134,170.945a483.614,483.614,0,0,1,12.533-50.66,473.038,473.038,0,0,0,34.74,201.061c9.329,22.821,24.76,57.455,51.029,95.4,82.533,86.839,198.945,140.9,327.852,140.9C641.792,958.012,762.635,899.133,845.675,805.636Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M746.1,868.708c162.87-18.86,234.969-186.7,142.381-190-83.633-2.673-219.527,198.9-142.381,190Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-3)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M900.207,644.424c112.056-65.214,82.839-206.08,82.839-206.08S939.8,488.582,910.421,568.664C881.4,647.963,832.837,683.812,900.207,644.424Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-4)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M544.474,952.062c156.227,49.851,290.5-73.22,207.733-114.32C676.956,800.676,470.324,928.49,544.474,952.062Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-5)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M911.849,704.234c3.8-5.363,8.94-22.535,13.48-30.211C952.911,629.5,953.106,594,953.106,593.187c16.659-83.219,15.148-117.2,4.9-180.043-8.251-50.6-44.322-123.092-75.57-158-32.2-35.965-9.514-24.247-40.692-50.518-27.327-30.293-53.823-60.291-68.253-72.355C669.215,45.094,671.571,26.577,673.579,23.42c-.339.371-.837.922-1.472,1.643C670.872,20.14,670,16,670,16s-57,57-69,152c-7.834,62.021,15.383,126.676,49,168a381.367,381.367,0,0,0,59,58l0-.026c25.4,36.477,39.38,81.489,39.38,129.909,0,121.244-98.341,219.531-219.652,219.531a220.455,220.455,0,0,1-49.134-5.519c-57.236-10.908-90.288-39.781-106.772-59.382-9.447-11.234-13.464-19.423-13.464-19.423,51.283,18.371,107.986,14.528,142.468-4.518,34.749-19.265,55.774-33.546,72.837-27.915,16.82,5.606,30.211-10.667,18.2-27.536-11.771-16.845-42.4-40.97-87.878-34.286-34.789,5.067-66.657,29.76-112.24,5.845a96.313,96.313,0,0,1-8.554-5.02c-3.005-1.771,9.768,2.695,6.787.682-8.87-4.318-24.573-13.728-28.643-17.074-.679-.557,6.883,2.161,6.2,1.6-42.621-31.449-37.3-52.693-35.959-66.018,1.073-10.66,8.814-24.32,21.859-29.86,6.3,3.081,10.226,5.433,10.226,5.433s-2.688-4.92-4.141-7.513c.509-.194.994-.145,1.5-.339,5.162,2.232,16.576,8.029,22.586,11.57,7.827,4.947,10.322,9.358,10.322,9.358s2.061-1.016.536-5.33c-.557-1.769-2.929-7.391-10.682-13.065l.485.049a90.851,90.851,0,0,1,13.134,8.173c2.186-7.121,6.118-14.557,5.253-27.859-.528-9.352-.284-11.775-2.124-15.386-1.647-3.1.924-4.312,3.782-1.088a30.038,30.038,0,0,0-2.444-7.343l.025-.242c3.57-11.143,75.535-40.125,80.773-43.513a70.31,70.31,0,0,0,21.175-20.63c4-5.715,7.014-13.733,7.748-25.895.246-5.48-1.441-9.817-20.5-13.965-11.439-2.49-29.136-4.913-56.433-7.474-19.9-1.756-31.577-14.676-38.212-26.6-1.211-2.569-2.445-4.9-3.68-7.222a53.108,53.108,0,0,1-2.831-8.36,158.47,158.47,0,0,1,61.279-76.063c1.6-1.308-6.4.335-4.8-.972,1.868-1.525,14.063-5.927,16.367-6.919,2.813-1.186-12.044-6.84-25.159-5.466-13.357,1.349-16.194,2.776-23.323,5.486,2.959-2.639,12.366-6.1,10.161-6.075-14.4,1.978-32.3,9.479-47.6,17.973a9.676,9.676,0,0,1,.924-4.312c-7.129,2.709-24.637,13.674-29.734,22.95a39.488,39.488,0,0,0,.294-5.354,88.678,88.678,0,0,0-14.6,13.7l-.267.218c-41.347-14.925-77.732-15.891-108.522-9.2-6.736-6.061-17.566-15.226-32.892-45.4-1.041-1.817-1.6,3.755-2.4,1.961-5.955-13.813-9.553-36.444-8.962-52.046,0,0-12.318,5.614-22.513,29.06-1.893,4.215-3.107,6.54-4.32,8.865-.558.678,1.265-7.7.974-7.244-1.772,3-6.356,7.192-8.371,12.618-1.384,4.021-3.325,6.273-4.564,11.288l-.291.46c-.1-1.478.367-6.081.027-5.137a236.1,236.1,0,0,0-12.308,29.841c-5.489,18.046-11.879,42.61-12.892,74.565-.244,2.423-.027,5.136-.247,7.317-13,14.844-21.858,27.413-25.207,33.928C75.18,329.762,56.66,370.236,38.707,434.259A319.143,319.143,0,0,1,67.245,384.27C52.316,418.253,37.885,471.618,35,553.8a438.522,438.522,0,0,1,13.872-50.24c-2.578,54.8,3.805,122.74,38.449,199.393,20.57,45.087,67.921,136.649,183.62,208.1l-.01.007s39.36,29.3,107.017,51.259c5,1.814,10.065,3.6,15.234,5.333-1.622-.655-3.191-1.344-4.715-2.052a484.883,484.883,0,0,0,138.8,20.4c175.18.149,226.846-70.2,226.846-70.2s-.182.137-.513.377q3.708-3.491,7.143-7.257c-27.639,26.1-90.715,27.832-114.3,25.949,40.223-11.813,66.691-21.806,118.175-41.519Q773.655,890,783.1,885.71c.681-.3,1.368-.625,2.052-.936,1.249-.582,2.486-1.132,3.747-1.744a349.205,349.205,0,0,0,70.262-43.987c51.7-41.3,62.949-81.557,68.829-108.1-.82,2.544-3.375,8.475-5.17,12.316-13.315,28.482-42.841,45.959-74.908,60.948A688.993,688.993,0,0,0,890.3,741.773C900.767,731.39,904.033,715.148,911.849,704.234Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-6)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M848.921,802.982c21.08-23.241,40.01-49.824,54.349-79.968,36.9-77.582,93.952-206.58,49.018-341.306C916.775,275.225,868.016,217,806.107,160.122,705.563,67.756,677.482,26.521,677.482,2c0,0-116.089,129.409-65.742,264.381S765.2,396.405,833.419,537.255C913.694,703,768.47,883.869,648.375,934.493c7.353-1.633,266.97-60.383,280.614-208.882C928.68,728.342,922.83,769.414,848.921,802.982Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-7)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M512.592,321.373c.393-8.77-4.156-14.66-76.682-21.463-29.839-2.755-41.265-30.334-44.748-41.941-10.61,27.565-14.991,56.49-12.636,91.477,1.61,22.92,17.009,47.521,24.37,61.965,0,0,1.636-2.126,2.391-2.912,13.861-14.431,71.936-36.419,77.392-39.541C488.693,365.159,511.582,348.435,512.592,321.373Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-2)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M193.314,158.471c-1.041-1.818-1.6,3.754-2.4,1.961-5.955-13.813-9.578-36.2-8.72-52.022,0,0-12.318,5.614-22.513,29.06-1.893,4.215-3.107,6.54-4.32,8.865-.558.678,1.265-7.7.974-7.244-1.771,3-6.355,7.192-8.346,12.375-1.651,4.239-3.349,6.515-4.613,11.772-.389,1.429.392-6.323.052-5.379-23.711,45.825-28.237,115.114-25.738,112.184,50.478-53.9,108.325-66.683,108.325-66.683-6.155-4.534-19.528-17.625-32.7-44.889Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-3)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M384.844,722.1c-69.724-29.769-148.992-71.755-146-167.138,4.075-125.619,117.145-100.791,117.145-100.791-4.267,1.039-15.675,9.162-19.718,17.82-4.273,10.827-12.069,35.276,11.551,60.9,37.089,40.192-76.2,95.356,98.663,199.567,4.41,2.4-40.991-1.43-61.639-10.358Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-4)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M360.074,659.5c49.442,17.207,107.04,14.189,141.523-4.858,23.085-12.851,52.7-33.434,70.922-28.353-15.777-6.236-27.726-9.15-42.1-9.862-2.448,0-5.382-.052-8.048-.32a136.228,136.228,0,0,0-15.757.863c-8.9.818-18.766,6.433-27.735,5.532-.485-.049,8.7-3.774,7.953-3.605-4.752.991-9.915,1.205-15.37,1.881-3.467.386-6.449.82-9.891.963-102.982,8.733-190.017-55.813-190.017-55.813-7.408,24.95,33.166,74.3,88.521,93.572Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-5)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M848.738,803.646C952.9,701.376,1005.6,577.061,983.321,437.627c0,0,8.9,71.5-24.848,144.628,16.213-71.393,18.1-160.114-24.975-251.988C876.005,207.636,781.45,143.109,745.351,116.189,690.656,75.4,667.983,33.87,667.574,25.3c-16.339,33.477-65.766,148.2-5.31,247,56.64,92.564,145.865,120.039,208.328,204.947C985.667,633.667,848.738,803.646,848.738,803.646Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-6)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M833.814,537.551C797.412,462.35,751.978,429.55,709,394c5,7,6.232,9.473,9,14,37.827,40.316,93.607,138.656,53.11,262.107C694.881,902.482,389.967,793.057,358,762.319c12.932,134.489,238.036,198.845,384.6,111.63C826,795,893.468,660.788,833.814,537.551Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-7)'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A") no-repeat center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: @Squeli47 Я не понимаю вашего вопроса. Все прекрасно тянется https://codepen.io/L2Banners/pen/NWpxMpr

Comment: @Get-Web url картинка и svg это две разные вещи

Comment: @InDevX в вопросе не было указано svg, а картинка в примере вообще была не доступна, это сейчас её поменяли. Какой вопрос такой и ответ. Опять же, вот тоже самое с свг, все прекрасно тянется https://codepen.io/L2Banners/pen/NWpxMpr

Comment: @Squeli47 вот так отвечаешь на тупые вопросы, а тебе автор еще и минусы ставит ну и кто он после этого?

Answer (score 0):

Пока нашел только такое решение, это svg править, добавил свойство к нему `preserveAspectRatio='none'`

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%0A%3Csvg preserveAspectRatio='none' id='Firefox_-_Large' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 0 1024 1024'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient' cx='-14480.522' cy='-8329.079' fx='-14509.281265145226' r='450.875' gradientTransform='matrix(0.762, 0.034, -0.05, 1.12, 11560.893, 10069.103)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.045' stop-color='%23ffea00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.12' stop-color='%23ffde00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.254' stop-color='%23ffbf00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.429' stop-color='%23ff8e00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.769' stop-color='%23ff272d'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.872' stop-color='%23e0255a'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.953' stop-color='%23cc2477'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23c42482'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-2' cx='-7529.669' cy='-7921.608' r='791.229' gradientTransform='translate(9921.963 9899.103) scale(1.225 1.225)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%2300ccda'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.22' stop-color='%230083ff'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.261' stop-color='%23007af9'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.33' stop-color='%230060e8'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.333' stop-color='%23005fe7'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.438' stop-color='%232639ad'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.522' stop-color='%23401e84'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.566' stop-color='%234a1475'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient' x1='575.669' y1='731.188' x2='384.231' y2='104.96' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23000f43' stop-opacity='0.4'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.485' stop-color='%23001962' stop-opacity='0.173'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23002079' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-3' cx='-8260.94' cy='-6516.556' r='266.886' gradientTransform='matrix(1.219, 0.123, -0.123, 1.219, 10296.265, 9597.23)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.003' stop-color='%23ffea00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.497' stop-color='%23ff272d'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23c42482'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-4' cx='-8285.087' cy='-6772.468' r='445.678' gradientTransform='matrix(1.219, 0.123, -0.123, 1.219, 10296.265, 9597.23)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.003' stop-color='%23ffe900'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.157' stop-color='%23ffaf0e'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.316' stop-color='%23ff7a1b'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.472' stop-color='%23ff4e26'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.621' stop-color='%23ff2c2e'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.762' stop-color='%23ff1434'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.892' stop-color='%23ff0538'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23ff0039'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-5' cx='-8222.051' cy='-6359.332' r='408.958' gradientTransform='matrix(1.219, 0.123, -0.123, 1.219, 10296.265, 9597.23)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.003' stop-color='%23ff272d'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.497' stop-color='%23c42482'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.986' stop-color='%23620700'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-6' cx='750.189' cy='396.041' fx='778.1665281038617' fy='382.2124050106231' r='782.18' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.156' stop-color='%23ffea00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.231' stop-color='%23ffde00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.365' stop-color='%23ffbf00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.541' stop-color='%23ff8e00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.763' stop-color='%23ff272d'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.796' stop-color='%23f92433'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.841' stop-color='%23e91c45'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.893' stop-color='%23cf0e62'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.935' stop-color='%23b5007f'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-7' cx='691.339' cy='3.289' r='923.615' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.279' stop-color='%23ffea00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.402' stop-color='%23fd0'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.63' stop-color='%23ffba00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.856' stop-color='%23ff9100'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.933' stop-color='%23ff6711'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.994' stop-color='%23ff4a1d'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-2' x1='-8944.65' y1='-6677.742' x2='-8660.289' y2='-6750.226' gradientTransform='matrix(1.219, 0.123, -0.123, 1.219, 10296.265, 9597.23)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.474' stop-color='%23ff272d' stop-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.486' stop-color='%23ff2c2c' stop-opacity='0.513'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.675' stop-color='%23ff7a1a' stop-opacity='0.72'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.829' stop-color='%23ffb20d' stop-opacity='0.871'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.942' stop-color='%23ffd605' stop-opacity='0.964'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23ffe302'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-3' x1='245.347' y1='-1082.012' x2='190.775' y2='-1221.859' gradientTransform='matrix(0.995, 0.1, -0.1, 0.995, -173.696, 1313.941)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23891551' stop-opacity='0.6'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-4' x1='22.04' y1='718.827' x2='116.148' y2='825.714' gradientTransform='matrix(0.995, 0.1, -0.1, 0.995, 305.439, -246.471)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.005' stop-color='%23891551' stop-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.484' stop-color='%23ff272d' stop-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23ff272d' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-5' x1='200.104' y1='904.616' x2='200.171' y2='829.835' gradientTransform='matrix(0.995, 0.1, -0.1, 0.995, 305.439, -246.471)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23c42482'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.083' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.81'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.206' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.565'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.328' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.362'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.447' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.204'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.562' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.091'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.673' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.023'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.773' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-6' x1='655.531' y1='38.12' x2='961.187' y2='721.615' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23fff14f'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.268' stop-color='%23ffee4c'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.452' stop-color='%23ffe643'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.612' stop-color='%23ffd834'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.757' stop-color='%23ffc41e'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.892' stop-color='%23ffab02'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.902' stop-color='%23ffa900'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.949' stop-color='%23ffa000'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23ff9100'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-7' x1='715.885' y1='431.21' x2='571.098' y2='819.96' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23ff8e00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.04' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.858'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.084' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.729'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.13' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.628'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.178' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.557'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.227' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.514'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.282' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.389' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.478'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.524' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.416'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.676' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.314'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.838' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.172'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Ctitle%3Efirefox-logo%3C/title%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath d='M805.285,93.558c-23.947,27.884-35.1,90.639-10.818,154.256s61.5,49.8,84.7,114.673c30.623,85.6,16.369,200.589,16.369,200.589s36.814,106.609,62.468-6.633C1014.787,343.74,805.285,145.937,805.285,93.558Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient)'/%3E%3Cpath id='_Path_' d='M513.072,976.638c245.236,0,443.9-199.739,443.9-446.028S758.308,84.583,513.31,84.583,69.65,284.322,69.65,530.61C69.175,777.137,268.073,976.638,513.072,976.638Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-2)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M845.675,805.636a246.888,246.888,0,0,1-30.123,18.183,704,704,0,0,0,38.3-62.961c9.46-10.47,18.126-20.648,25.188-31.653,3.437-5.407,7.313-12.079,11.416-19.819,24.921-44.9,52.4-117.563,53.179-192.2l0-.18c.018-1.837.029-3.675.014-5.515a257.6,257.6,0,0,0-5.712-55.748c.2,1.431.376,2.861.556,4.291-.221-1.1-.407-2.212-.644-3.314.366,2.034.66,4,.976,5.983,5.094,43.217,1.466,85.372-16.682,116.45-.286.454-.58.879-.869,1.323,9.41-47.234,12.558-99.387,2.088-151.6,0,0-4.187-25.383-35.376-102.441-17.952-44.353-49.833-80.716-78-107.207-24.69-30.546-47.114-51.045-59.475-64.06-25.821-27.189-36.643-47.569-41.087-60.867-3.853-1.932-53.135-49.807-57.05-51.631-21.511,33.352-89.162,137.675-56.981,235.146,14.584,44.172,51.467,90.017,90.067,115.736,1.695,1.936,22.969,25.042,33.086,77.157C728.992,524.551,723.5,566.564,702,628.692c-25.286,54.505-90.067,108.388-150.724,113.9C421.6,754.373,374.127,677.484,374.127,677.484c46.336,18.525,97.568,14.65,128.724-4.556,31.4-19.425,50.394-33.827,65.81-28.148,15.2,5.653,27.3-10.756,16.442-27.767a78.5,78.5,0,0,0-79.4-34.573c-31.433,5.109-60.226,30.009-101.412,5.894a85.528,85.528,0,0,1-7.729-5.062c-2.715-1.785,8.826,2.717,6.133.688-8.015-4.354-22.2-13.842-25.88-17.217-.613-.562,6.219,2.179,5.606,1.616-38.51-31.712-33.7-53.134-32.49-66.57.969-10.749,7.964-24.523,19.751-30.11,5.693,3.107,9.24,5.479,9.24,5.479s-2.428-4.961-3.741-7.576c.46-.2.9-.147,1.358-.342,4.664,2.251,14.977,8.1,20.407,11.667,7.072,4.988,9.326,9.436,9.326,9.436s1.862-1.025.485-5.375c-.5-1.784-2.647-7.453-9.652-13.174l.438.049a81.2,81.2,0,0,1,11.867,8.241c1.975-7.181,5.527-14.679,4.746-28.092-.477-9.431-.257-11.873-1.919-15.515-1.488-3.128.834-4.348,3.418-1.1a32.826,32.826,0,0,0-2.208-7.4l.022-.244c3.225-11.236,68.248-40.461,72.981-43.877a67.355,67.355,0,0,0,19.132-20.8c3.617-5.763,6.337-13.848,7-26.112.355-8.844-3.759-14.734-69.507-21.618-17.981-1.771-28.531-14.8-34.526-26.823-1.094-2.59-2.209-4.937-3.325-7.282a58,58,0,0,1-2.558-8.431c10.749-30.873,28.81-56.977,55.367-76.7,1.447-1.318-5.782.338-4.336-.98,1.687-1.538,12.706-5.977,14.787-6.977,2.542-1.2-10.882-6.9-22.732-5.512-12.069,1.36-14.632,2.8-21.073,5.531,2.673-2.661,11.173-6.149,9.18-6.126-13.011,1.995-29.179,9.558-43,18.124a10.731,10.731,0,0,1,.835-4.348c-6.441,2.732-22.26,13.788-26.865,23.142a44.329,44.329,0,0,0,.266-5.4A84.483,84.483,0,0,0,351.9,227.362l-.241.219c-37.358-15.05-70.233-16.024-98.053-9.276-6.086-6.112-9.059-1.644-22.907-32.069-.941-1.832.722,1.809,0,0-2.278-5.9,1.389,7.872,0,0-23.284,18.372-53.92,39.193-68.626,53.89-.182.586,17.156-4.9,0,0-6.008,1.716-5.6,5.281-6.513,37.5-.22,2.443-.025,5.179-.223,7.378-11.748,14.968-19.749,27.643-22.775,34.211-15.193,26.18-31.926,66.992-48.146,131.551A334.364,334.364,0,0,1,110.2,400.365c-13.488,34.267-26.527,88.078-29.134,170.945a483.614,483.614,0,0,1,12.533-50.66,473.038,473.038,0,0,0,34.74,201.061c9.329,22.821,24.76,57.455,51.029,95.4,82.533,86.839,198.945,140.9,327.852,140.9C641.792,958.012,762.635,899.133,845.675,805.636Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M746.1,868.708c162.87-18.86,234.969-186.7,142.381-190-83.633-2.673-219.527,198.9-142.381,190Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-3)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M900.207,644.424c112.056-65.214,82.839-206.08,82.839-206.08S939.8,488.582,910.421,568.664C881.4,647.963,832.837,683.812,900.207,644.424Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-4)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M544.474,952.062c156.227,49.851,290.5-73.22,207.733-114.32C676.956,800.676,470.324,928.49,544.474,952.062Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-5)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M911.849,704.234c3.8-5.363,8.94-22.535,13.48-30.211C952.911,629.5,953.106,594,953.106,593.187c16.659-83.219,15.148-117.2,4.9-180.043-8.251-50.6-44.322-123.092-75.57-158-32.2-35.965-9.514-24.247-40.692-50.518-27.327-30.293-53.823-60.291-68.253-72.355C669.215,45.094,671.571,26.577,673.579,23.42c-.339.371-.837.922-1.472,1.643C670.872,20.14,670,16,670,16s-57,57-69,152c-7.834,62.021,15.383,126.676,49,168a381.367,381.367,0,0,0,59,58l0-.026c25.4,36.477,39.38,81.489,39.38,129.909,0,121.244-98.341,219.531-219.652,219.531a220.455,220.455,0,0,1-49.134-5.519c-57.236-10.908-90.288-39.781-106.772-59.382-9.447-11.234-13.464-19.423-13.464-19.423,51.283,18.371,107.986,14.528,142.468-4.518,34.749-19.265,55.774-33.546,72.837-27.915,16.82,5.606,30.211-10.667,18.2-27.536-11.771-16.845-42.4-40.97-87.878-34.286-34.789,5.067-66.657,29.76-112.24,5.845a96.313,96.313,0,0,1-8.554-5.02c-3.005-1.771,9.768,2.695,6.787.682-8.87-4.318-24.573-13.728-28.643-17.074-.679-.557,6.883,2.161,6.2,1.6-42.621-31.449-37.3-52.693-35.959-66.018,1.073-10.66,8.814-24.32,21.859-29.86,6.3,3.081,10.226,5.433,10.226,5.433s-2.688-4.92-4.141-7.513c.509-.194.994-.145,1.5-.339,5.162,2.232,16.576,8.029,22.586,11.57,7.827,4.947,10.322,9.358,10.322,9.358s2.061-1.016.536-5.33c-.557-1.769-2.929-7.391-10.682-13.065l.485.049a90.851,90.851,0,0,1,13.134,8.173c2.186-7.121,6.118-14.557,5.253-27.859-.528-9.352-.284-11.775-2.124-15.386-1.647-3.1.924-4.312,3.782-1.088a30.038,30.038,0,0,0-2.444-7.343l.025-.242c3.57-11.143,75.535-40.125,80.773-43.513a70.31,70.31,0,0,0,21.175-20.63c4-5.715,7.014-13.733,7.748-25.895.246-5.48-1.441-9.817-20.5-13.965-11.439-2.49-29.136-4.913-56.433-7.474-19.9-1.756-31.577-14.676-38.212-26.6-1.211-2.569-2.445-4.9-3.68-7.222a53.108,53.108,0,0,1-2.831-8.36,158.47,158.47,0,0,1,61.279-76.063c1.6-1.308-6.4.335-4.8-.972,1.868-1.525,14.063-5.927,16.367-6.919,2.813-1.186-12.044-6.84-25.159-5.466-13.357,1.349-16.194,2.776-23.323,5.486,2.959-2.639,12.366-6.1,10.161-6.075-14.4,1.978-32.3,9.479-47.6,17.973a9.676,9.676,0,0,1,.924-4.312c-7.129,2.709-24.637,13.674-29.734,22.95a39.488,39.488,0,0,0,.294-5.354,88.678,88.678,0,0,0-14.6,13.7l-.267.218c-41.347-14.925-77.732-15.891-108.522-9.2-6.736-6.061-17.566-15.226-32.892-45.4-1.041-1.817-1.6,3.755-2.4,1.961-5.955-13.813-9.553-36.444-8.962-52.046,0,0-12.318,5.614-22.513,29.06-1.893,4.215-3.107,6.54-4.32,8.865-.558.678,1.265-7.7.974-7.244-1.772,3-6.356,7.192-8.371,12.618-1.384,4.021-3.325,6.273-4.564,11.288l-.291.46c-.1-1.478.367-6.081.027-5.137a236.1,236.1,0,0,0-12.308,29.841c-5.489,18.046-11.879,42.61-12.892,74.565-.244,2.423-.027,5.136-.247,7.317-13,14.844-21.858,27.413-25.207,33.928C75.18,329.762,56.66,370.236,38.707,434.259A319.143,319.143,0,0,1,67.245,384.27C52.316,418.253,37.885,471.618,35,553.8a438.522,438.522,0,0,1,13.872-50.24c-2.578,54.8,3.805,122.74,38.449,199.393,20.57,45.087,67.921,136.649,183.62,208.1l-.01.007s39.36,29.3,107.017,51.259c5,1.814,10.065,3.6,15.234,5.333-1.622-.655-3.191-1.344-4.715-2.052a484.883,484.883,0,0,0,138.8,20.4c175.18.149,226.846-70.2,226.846-70.2s-.182.137-.513.377q3.708-3.491,7.143-7.257c-27.639,26.1-90.715,27.832-114.3,25.949,40.223-11.813,66.691-21.806,118.175-41.519Q773.655,890,783.1,885.71c.681-.3,1.368-.625,2.052-.936,1.249-.582,2.486-1.132,3.747-1.744a349.205,349.205,0,0,0,70.262-43.987c51.7-41.3,62.949-81.557,68.829-108.1-.82,2.544-3.375,8.475-5.17,12.316-13.315,28.482-42.841,45.959-74.908,60.948A688.993,688.993,0,0,0,890.3,741.773C900.767,731.39,904.033,715.148,911.849,704.234Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-6)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M848.921,802.982c21.08-23.241,40.01-49.824,54.349-79.968,36.9-77.582,93.952-206.58,49.018-341.306C916.775,275.225,868.016,217,806.107,160.122,705.563,67.756,677.482,26.521,677.482,2c0,0-116.089,129.409-65.742,264.381S765.2,396.405,833.419,537.255C913.694,703,768.47,883.869,648.375,934.493c7.353-1.633,266.97-60.383,280.614-208.882C928.68,728.342,922.83,769.414,848.921,802.982Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-7)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M512.592,321.373c.393-8.77-4.156-14.66-76.682-21.463-29.839-2.755-41.265-30.334-44.748-41.941-10.61,27.565-14.991,56.49-12.636,91.477,1.61,22.92,17.009,47.521,24.37,61.965,0,0,1.636-2.126,2.391-2.912,13.861-14.431,71.936-36.419,77.392-39.541C488.693,365.159,511.582,348.435,512.592,321.373Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-2)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M193.314,158.471c-1.041-1.818-1.6,3.754-2.4,1.961-5.955-13.813-9.578-36.2-8.72-52.022,0,0-12.318,5.614-22.513,29.06-1.893,4.215-3.107,6.54-4.32,8.865-.558.678,1.265-7.7.974-7.244-1.771,3-6.355,7.192-8.346,12.375-1.651,4.239-3.349,6.515-4.613,11.772-.389,1.429.392-6.323.052-5.379-23.711,45.825-28.237,115.114-25.738,112.184,50.478-53.9,108.325-66.683,108.325-66.683-6.155-4.534-19.528-17.625-32.7-44.889Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-3)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M384.844,722.1c-69.724-29.769-148.992-71.755-146-167.138,4.075-125.619,117.145-100.791,117.145-100.791-4.267,1.039-15.675,9.162-19.718,17.82-4.273,10.827-12.069,35.276,11.551,60.9,37.089,40.192-76.2,95.356,98.663,199.567,4.41,2.4-40.991-1.43-61.639-10.358Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-4)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M360.074,659.5c49.442,17.207,107.04,14.189,141.523-4.858,23.085-12.851,52.7-33.434,70.922-28.353-15.777-6.236-27.726-9.15-42.1-9.862-2.448,0-5.382-.052-8.048-.32a136.228,136.228,0,0,0-15.757.863c-8.9.818-18.766,6.433-27.735,5.532-.485-.049,8.7-3.774,7.953-3.605-4.752.991-9.915,1.205-15.37,1.881-3.467.386-6.449.82-9.891.963-102.982,8.733-190.017-55.813-190.017-55.813-7.408,24.95,33.166,74.3,88.521,93.572Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-5)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M848.738,803.646C952.9,701.376,1005.6,577.061,983.321,437.627c0,0,8.9,71.5-24.848,144.628,16.213-71.393,18.1-160.114-24.975-251.988C876.005,207.636,781.45,143.109,745.351,116.189,690.656,75.4,667.983,33.87,667.574,25.3c-16.339,33.477-65.766,148.2-5.31,247,56.64,92.564,145.865,120.039,208.328,204.947C985.667,633.667,848.738,803.646,848.738,803.646Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-6)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M833.814,537.551C797.412,462.35,751.978,429.55,709,394c5,7,6.232,9.473,9,14,37.827,40.316,93.607,138.656,53.11,262.107C694.881,902.482,389.967,793.057,358,762.319c12.932,134.489,238.036,198.845,384.6,111.63C826,795,893.468,660.788,833.814,537.551Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-7)'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 360px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Firefox - не работает.

Comment: Добавьте width, height ту же, что для .container прописана, должно пофиксить ff (это у них старая проблема..)

Answer (score 0):

Вот, нарыл, вроде как легально все

```css
.bg-svg {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%0A%3Csvg id='Firefox_-_Large' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 0 1024 1024'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient' cx='-14480.522' cy='-8329.079' fx='-14509.281265145226' r='450.875' gradientTransform='matrix(0.762, 0.034, -0.05, 1.12, 11560.893, 10069.103)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.045' stop-color='%23ffea00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.12' stop-color='%23ffde00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.254' stop-color='%23ffbf00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.429' stop-color='%23ff8e00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.769' stop-color='%23ff272d'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.872' stop-color='%23e0255a'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.953' stop-color='%23cc2477'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23c42482'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-2' cx='-7529.669' cy='-7921.608' r='791.229' gradientTransform='translate(9921.963 9899.103) scale(1.225 1.225)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%2300ccda'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.22' stop-color='%230083ff'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.261' stop-color='%23007af9'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.33' stop-color='%230060e8'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.333' stop-color='%23005fe7'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.438' stop-color='%232639ad'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.522' stop-color='%23401e84'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.566' stop-color='%234a1475'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient' x1='575.669' y1='731.188' x2='384.231' y2='104.96' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23000f43' stop-opacity='0.4'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.485' stop-color='%23001962' stop-opacity='0.173'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23002079' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-3' cx='-8260.94' cy='-6516.556' r='266.886' gradientTransform='matrix(1.219, 0.123, -0.123, 1.219, 10296.265, 9597.23)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.003' stop-color='%23ffea00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.497' stop-color='%23ff272d'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23c42482'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-4' cx='-8285.087' cy='-6772.468' r='445.678' gradientTransform='matrix(1.219, 0.123, -0.123, 1.219, 10296.265, 9597.23)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.003' stop-color='%23ffe900'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.157' stop-color='%23ffaf0e'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.316' stop-color='%23ff7a1b'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.472' stop-color='%23ff4e26'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.621' stop-color='%23ff2c2e'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.762' stop-color='%23ff1434'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.892' stop-color='%23ff0538'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23ff0039'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-5' cx='-8222.051' cy='-6359.332' r='408.958' gradientTransform='matrix(1.219, 0.123, -0.123, 1.219, 10296.265, 9597.23)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.003' stop-color='%23ff272d'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.497' stop-color='%23c42482'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.986' stop-color='%23620700'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-6' cx='750.189' cy='396.041' fx='778.1665281038617' fy='382.2124050106231' r='782.18' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.156' stop-color='%23ffea00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.231' stop-color='%23ffde00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.365' stop-color='%23ffbf00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.541' stop-color='%23ff8e00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.763' stop-color='%23ff272d'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.796' stop-color='%23f92433'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.841' stop-color='%23e91c45'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.893' stop-color='%23cf0e62'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.935' stop-color='%23b5007f'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3CradialGradient id='radial-gradient-7' cx='691.339' cy='3.289' r='923.615' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.279' stop-color='%23ffea00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.402' stop-color='%23fd0'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.63' stop-color='%23ffba00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.856' stop-color='%23ff9100'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.933' stop-color='%23ff6711'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.994' stop-color='%23ff4a1d'/%3E%3C/radialGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-2' x1='-8944.65' y1='-6677.742' x2='-8660.289' y2='-6750.226' gradientTransform='matrix(1.219, 0.123, -0.123, 1.219, 10296.265, 9597.23)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.474' stop-color='%23ff272d' stop-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.486' stop-color='%23ff2c2c' stop-opacity='0.513'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.675' stop-color='%23ff7a1a' stop-opacity='0.72'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.829' stop-color='%23ffb20d' stop-opacity='0.871'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.942' stop-color='%23ffd605' stop-opacity='0.964'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23ffe302'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-3' x1='245.347' y1='-1082.012' x2='190.775' y2='-1221.859' gradientTransform='matrix(0.995, 0.1, -0.1, 0.995, -173.696, 1313.941)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23891551' stop-opacity='0.6'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-4' x1='22.04' y1='718.827' x2='116.148' y2='825.714' gradientTransform='matrix(0.995, 0.1, -0.1, 0.995, 305.439, -246.471)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0.005' stop-color='%23891551' stop-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.484' stop-color='%23ff272d' stop-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23ff272d' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-5' x1='200.104' y1='904.616' x2='200.171' y2='829.835' gradientTransform='matrix(0.995, 0.1, -0.1, 0.995, 305.439, -246.471)' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23c42482'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.083' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.81'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.206' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.565'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.328' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.362'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.447' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.204'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.562' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.091'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.673' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0.023'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.773' stop-color='%23c42482' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-6' x1='655.531' y1='38.12' x2='961.187' y2='721.615' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23fff14f'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.268' stop-color='%23ffee4c'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.452' stop-color='%23ffe643'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.612' stop-color='%23ffd834'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.757' stop-color='%23ffc41e'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.892' stop-color='%23ffab02'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.902' stop-color='%23ffa900'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.949' stop-color='%23ffa000'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23ff9100'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='linear-gradient-7' x1='715.885' y1='431.21' x2='571.098' y2='819.96' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23ff8e00'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.04' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.858'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.084' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.729'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.13' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.628'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.178' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.557'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.227' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.514'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.282' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.389' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.478'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.524' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.416'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.676' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.314'/%3E%3Cstop offset='0.838' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0.172'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23ff8e00' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Ctitle%3Efirefox-logo%3C/title%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath d='M805.285,93.558c-23.947,27.884-35.1,90.639-10.818,154.256s61.5,49.8,84.7,114.673c30.623,85.6,16.369,200.589,16.369,200.589s36.814,106.609,62.468-6.633C1014.787,343.74,805.285,145.937,805.285,93.558Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient)'/%3E%3Cpath id='_Path_' d='M513.072,976.638c245.236,0,443.9-199.739,443.9-446.028S758.308,84.583,513.31,84.583,69.65,284.322,69.65,530.61C69.175,777.137,268.073,976.638,513.072,976.638Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-2)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M845.675,805.636a246.888,246.888,0,0,1-30.123,18.183,704,704,0,0,0,38.3-62.961c9.46-10.47,18.126-20.648,25.188-31.653,3.437-5.407,7.313-12.079,11.416-19.819,24.921-44.9,52.4-117.563,53.179-192.2l0-.18c.018-1.837.029-3.675.014-5.515a257.6,257.6,0,0,0-5.712-55.748c.2,1.431.376,2.861.556,4.291-.221-1.1-.407-2.212-.644-3.314.366,2.034.66,4,.976,5.983,5.094,43.217,1.466,85.372-16.682,116.45-.286.454-.58.879-.869,1.323,9.41-47.234,12.558-99.387,2.088-151.6,0,0-4.187-25.383-35.376-102.441-17.952-44.353-49.833-80.716-78-107.207-24.69-30.546-47.114-51.045-59.475-64.06-25.821-27.189-36.643-47.569-41.087-60.867-3.853-1.932-53.135-49.807-57.05-51.631-21.511,33.352-89.162,137.675-56.981,235.146,14.584,44.172,51.467,90.017,90.067,115.736,1.695,1.936,22.969,25.042,33.086,77.157C728.992,524.551,723.5,566.564,702,628.692c-25.286,54.505-90.067,108.388-150.724,113.9C421.6,754.373,374.127,677.484,374.127,677.484c46.336,18.525,97.568,14.65,128.724-4.556,31.4-19.425,50.394-33.827,65.81-28.148,15.2,5.653,27.3-10.756,16.442-27.767a78.5,78.5,0,0,0-79.4-34.573c-31.433,5.109-60.226,30.009-101.412,5.894a85.528,85.528,0,0,1-7.729-5.062c-2.715-1.785,8.826,2.717,6.133.688-8.015-4.354-22.2-13.842-25.88-17.217-.613-.562,6.219,2.179,5.606,1.616-38.51-31.712-33.7-53.134-32.49-66.57.969-10.749,7.964-24.523,19.751-30.11,5.693,3.107,9.24,5.479,9.24,5.479s-2.428-4.961-3.741-7.576c.46-.2.9-.147,1.358-.342,4.664,2.251,14.977,8.1,20.407,11.667,7.072,4.988,9.326,9.436,9.326,9.436s1.862-1.025.485-5.375c-.5-1.784-2.647-7.453-9.652-13.174l.438.049a81.2,81.2,0,0,1,11.867,8.241c1.975-7.181,5.527-14.679,4.746-28.092-.477-9.431-.257-11.873-1.919-15.515-1.488-3.128.834-4.348,3.418-1.1a32.826,32.826,0,0,0-2.208-7.4l.022-.244c3.225-11.236,68.248-40.461,72.981-43.877a67.355,67.355,0,0,0,19.132-20.8c3.617-5.763,6.337-13.848,7-26.112.355-8.844-3.759-14.734-69.507-21.618-17.981-1.771-28.531-14.8-34.526-26.823-1.094-2.59-2.209-4.937-3.325-7.282a58,58,0,0,1-2.558-8.431c10.749-30.873,28.81-56.977,55.367-76.7,1.447-1.318-5.782.338-4.336-.98,1.687-1.538,12.706-5.977,14.787-6.977,2.542-1.2-10.882-6.9-22.732-5.512-12.069,1.36-14.632,2.8-21.073,5.531,2.673-2.661,11.173-6.149,9.18-6.126-13.011,1.995-29.179,9.558-43,18.124a10.731,10.731,0,0,1,.835-4.348c-6.441,2.732-22.26,13.788-26.865,23.142a44.329,44.329,0,0,0,.266-5.4A84.483,84.483,0,0,0,351.9,227.362l-.241.219c-37.358-15.05-70.233-16.024-98.053-9.276-6.086-6.112-9.059-1.644-22.907-32.069-.941-1.832.722,1.809,0,0-2.278-5.9,1.389,7.872,0,0-23.284,18.372-53.92,39.193-68.626,53.89-.182.586,17.156-4.9,0,0-6.008,1.716-5.6,5.281-6.513,37.5-.22,2.443-.025,5.179-.223,7.378-11.748,14.968-19.749,27.643-22.775,34.211-15.193,26.18-31.926,66.992-48.146,131.551A334.364,334.364,0,0,1,110.2,400.365c-13.488,34.267-26.527,88.078-29.134,170.945a483.614,483.614,0,0,1,12.533-50.66,473.038,473.038,0,0,0,34.74,201.061c9.329,22.821,24.76,57.455,51.029,95.4,82.533,86.839,198.945,140.9,327.852,140.9C641.792,958.012,762.635,899.133,845.675,805.636Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M746.1,868.708c162.87-18.86,234.969-186.7,142.381-190-83.633-2.673-219.527,198.9-142.381,190Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-3)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M900.207,644.424c112.056-65.214,82.839-206.08,82.839-206.08S939.8,488.582,910.421,568.664C881.4,647.963,832.837,683.812,900.207,644.424Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-4)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M544.474,952.062c156.227,49.851,290.5-73.22,207.733-114.32C676.956,800.676,470.324,928.49,544.474,952.062Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-5)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M911.849,704.234c3.8-5.363,8.94-22.535,13.48-30.211C952.911,629.5,953.106,594,953.106,593.187c16.659-83.219,15.148-117.2,4.9-180.043-8.251-50.6-44.322-123.092-75.57-158-32.2-35.965-9.514-24.247-40.692-50.518-27.327-30.293-53.823-60.291-68.253-72.355C669.215,45.094,671.571,26.577,673.579,23.42c-.339.371-.837.922-1.472,1.643C670.872,20.14,670,16,670,16s-57,57-69,152c-7.834,62.021,15.383,126.676,49,168a381.367,381.367,0,0,0,59,58l0-.026c25.4,36.477,39.38,81.489,39.38,129.909,0,121.244-98.341,219.531-219.652,219.531a220.455,220.455,0,0,1-49.134-5.519c-57.236-10.908-90.288-39.781-106.772-59.382-9.447-11.234-13.464-19.423-13.464-19.423,51.283,18.371,107.986,14.528,142.468-4.518,34.749-19.265,55.774-33.546,72.837-27.915,16.82,5.606,30.211-10.667,18.2-27.536-11.771-16.845-42.4-40.97-87.878-34.286-34.789,5.067-66.657,29.76-112.24,5.845a96.313,96.313,0,0,1-8.554-5.02c-3.005-1.771,9.768,2.695,6.787.682-8.87-4.318-24.573-13.728-28.643-17.074-.679-.557,6.883,2.161,6.2,1.6-42.621-31.449-37.3-52.693-35.959-66.018,1.073-10.66,8.814-24.32,21.859-29.86,6.3,3.081,10.226,5.433,10.226,5.433s-2.688-4.92-4.141-7.513c.509-.194.994-.145,1.5-.339,5.162,2.232,16.576,8.029,22.586,11.57,7.827,4.947,10.322,9.358,10.322,9.358s2.061-1.016.536-5.33c-.557-1.769-2.929-7.391-10.682-13.065l.485.049a90.851,90.851,0,0,1,13.134,8.173c2.186-7.121,6.118-14.557,5.253-27.859-.528-9.352-.284-11.775-2.124-15.386-1.647-3.1.924-4.312,3.782-1.088a30.038,30.038,0,0,0-2.444-7.343l.025-.242c3.57-11.143,75.535-40.125,80.773-43.513a70.31,70.31,0,0,0,21.175-20.63c4-5.715,7.014-13.733,7.748-25.895.246-5.48-1.441-9.817-20.5-13.965-11.439-2.49-29.136-4.913-56.433-7.474-19.9-1.756-31.577-14.676-38.212-26.6-1.211-2.569-2.445-4.9-3.68-7.222a53.108,53.108,0,0,1-2.831-8.36,158.47,158.47,0,0,1,61.279-76.063c1.6-1.308-6.4.335-4.8-.972,1.868-1.525,14.063-5.927,16.367-6.919,2.813-1.186-12.044-6.84-25.159-5.466-13.357,1.349-16.194,2.776-23.323,5.486,2.959-2.639,12.366-6.1,10.161-6.075-14.4,1.978-32.3,9.479-47.6,17.973a9.676,9.676,0,0,1,.924-4.312c-7.129,2.709-24.637,13.674-29.734,22.95a39.488,39.488,0,0,0,.294-5.354,88.678,88.678,0,0,0-14.6,13.7l-.267.218c-41.347-14.925-77.732-15.891-108.522-9.2-6.736-6.061-17.566-15.226-32.892-45.4-1.041-1.817-1.6,3.755-2.4,1.961-5.955-13.813-9.553-36.444-8.962-52.046,0,0-12.318,5.614-22.513,29.06-1.893,4.215-3.107,6.54-4.32,8.865-.558.678,1.265-7.7.974-7.244-1.772,3-6.356,7.192-8.371,12.618-1.384,4.021-3.325,6.273-4.564,11.288l-.291.46c-.1-1.478.367-6.081.027-5.137a236.1,236.1,0,0,0-12.308,29.841c-5.489,18.046-11.879,42.61-12.892,74.565-.244,2.423-.027,5.136-.247,7.317-13,14.844-21.858,27.413-25.207,33.928C75.18,329.762,56.66,370.236,38.707,434.259A319.143,319.143,0,0,1,67.245,384.27C52.316,418.253,37.885,471.618,35,553.8a438.522,438.522,0,0,1,13.872-50.24c-2.578,54.8,3.805,122.74,38.449,199.393,20.57,45.087,67.921,136.649,183.62,208.1l-.01.007s39.36,29.3,107.017,51.259c5,1.814,10.065,3.6,15.234,5.333-1.622-.655-3.191-1.344-4.715-2.052a484.883,484.883,0,0,0,138.8,20.4c175.18.149,226.846-70.2,226.846-70.2s-.182.137-.513.377q3.708-3.491,7.143-7.257c-27.639,26.1-90.715,27.832-114.3,25.949,40.223-11.813,66.691-21.806,118.175-41.519Q773.655,890,783.1,885.71c.681-.3,1.368-.625,2.052-.936,1.249-.582,2.486-1.132,3.747-1.744a349.205,349.205,0,0,0,70.262-43.987c51.7-41.3,62.949-81.557,68.829-108.1-.82,2.544-3.375,8.475-5.17,12.316-13.315,28.482-42.841,45.959-74.908,60.948A688.993,688.993,0,0,0,890.3,741.773C900.767,731.39,904.033,715.148,911.849,704.234Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-6)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M848.921,802.982c21.08-23.241,40.01-49.824,54.349-79.968,36.9-77.582,93.952-206.58,49.018-341.306C916.775,275.225,868.016,217,806.107,160.122,705.563,67.756,677.482,26.521,677.482,2c0,0-116.089,129.409-65.742,264.381S765.2,396.405,833.419,537.255C913.694,703,768.47,883.869,648.375,934.493c7.353-1.633,266.97-60.383,280.614-208.882C928.68,728.342,922.83,769.414,848.921,802.982Z' style='fill: url(%23radial-gradient-7)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M512.592,321.373c.393-8.77-4.156-14.66-76.682-21.463-29.839-2.755-41.265-30.334-44.748-41.941-10.61,27.565-14.991,56.49-12.636,91.477,1.61,22.92,17.009,47.521,24.37,61.965,0,0,1.636-2.126,2.391-2.912,13.861-14.431,71.936-36.419,77.392-39.541C488.693,365.159,511.582,348.435,512.592,321.373Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-2)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M193.314,158.471c-1.041-1.818-1.6,3.754-2.4,1.961-5.955-13.813-9.578-36.2-8.72-52.022,0,0-12.318,5.614-22.513,29.06-1.893,4.215-3.107,6.54-4.32,8.865-.558.678,1.265-7.7.974-7.244-1.771,3-6.355,7.192-8.346,12.375-1.651,4.239-3.349,6.515-4.613,11.772-.389,1.429.392-6.323.052-5.379-23.711,45.825-28.237,115.114-25.738,112.184,50.478-53.9,108.325-66.683,108.325-66.683-6.155-4.534-19.528-17.625-32.7-44.889Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-3)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M384.844,722.1c-69.724-29.769-148.992-71.755-146-167.138,4.075-125.619,117.145-100.791,117.145-100.791-4.267,1.039-15.675,9.162-19.718,17.82-4.273,10.827-12.069,35.276,11.551,60.9,37.089,40.192-76.2,95.356,98.663,199.567,4.41,2.4-40.991-1.43-61.639-10.358Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-4)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M360.074,659.5c49.442,17.207,107.04,14.189,141.523-4.858,23.085-12.851,52.7-33.434,70.922-28.353-15.777-6.236-27.726-9.15-42.1-9.862-2.448,0-5.382-.052-8.048-.32a136.228,136.228,0,0,0-15.757.863c-8.9.818-18.766,6.433-27.735,5.532-.485-.049,8.7-3.774,7.953-3.605-4.752.991-9.915,1.205-15.37,1.881-3.467.386-6.449.82-9.891.963-102.982,8.733-190.017-55.813-190.017-55.813-7.408,24.95,33.166,74.3,88.521,93.572Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-5)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M848.738,803.646C952.9,701.376,1005.6,577.061,983.321,437.627c0,0,8.9,71.5-24.848,144.628,16.213-71.393,18.1-160.114-24.975-251.988C876.005,207.636,781.45,143.109,745.351,116.189,690.656,75.4,667.983,33.87,667.574,25.3c-16.339,33.477-65.766,148.2-5.31,247,56.64,92.564,145.865,120.039,208.328,204.947C985.667,633.667,848.738,803.646,848.738,803.646Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-6)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M833.814,537.551C797.412,462.35,751.978,429.55,709,394c5,7,6.232,9.473,9,14,37.827,40.316,93.607,138.656,53.11,262.107C694.881,902.482,389.967,793.057,358,762.319c12.932,134.489,238.036,198.845,384.6,111.63C826,795,893.468,660.788,833.814,537.551Z' style='fill: url(%23linear-gradient-7)'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0; /* reset */
  padding-bottom: 92%;
  border: thin dotted darkgrey;
}
figure > div {
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <figcaption>CSS background image, full width</figcaption>
  <div>
    <div class="bg-svg">
  </div>
</figure>
```

Comment: `padding-bottom: 50%;` и всё ломается. Хотя и без этого видно что не то... Фон растягиваться на всю ширину и высоту блока должен

Comment: Доброй ночи) 1. если хотите поменять padding-bottom то нужно менять для элемента figure тоже самое касается и изменения размеров и margin, и тогда ничего не собьется. 2. Автор выше кинул код в котором указал как он хочет это реализовать, просто хотел на css and html, без коррекции SVG. Я оттолкнулся от результатов его кода, сделал тот же самый результат но на html, css. И я так понял что автора мое решение устроило.

Comment: _без коррекции SVG_ это где такое указано? _ автора мое решение устроило._ если бы устроило - был бы ответ с галочкой